# Thread communication in unix

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, unix, pthreads

i have written a program where the main thread creates a thread and sends an event whenever the secondary thread has to work upon, this works perfectly fine on windows but when porting the same to *nix its difficult to achieve the same.

let me explain, please consider the following

```
/* thread2 function */
thread_function_call()  
{  
   /* be a consumer */

 pthread_exit();  
}  


/* main function */  
main()  
{  

  /* create a thread */  
  pthread_create();  

  while(1)  
   {  
       /* produce the stuff for consumer or thread2 */  
        /* generate the event */  
   }   

 pthread_join();  
}
```

Here the main thread in a continuous loop and then triggers the event/calls the thread2, once it triggers the event/calls thread2,  the thread2 function should execute.

this is something like producer and consumer problem, please do consider that all synchronization conditions are in place.

please help me in how best we can achieve this

Comment: Thanks Anders K. for editing the code properly

Answer (score 2):

The general way to implement a producer-consumer with pthreads is to use a *condition variable*.  The consumer thread(s) block in `pthread_cond_wait()`, and the producer signals it/them with `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()`.

Comment: thanks, but i have already tried this, the consumer thread has to run only when it signaled and the rest of the time it should for the conditional variable to set.

Comment: @Venkat: You will have to explain better what the problem you are encountering is.